# What parts do I need for a bathroom sink trap?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, sink, p-trap, abs

I'm replacing the bathroom vanity cabinet, sink and countertop, located between two walls. Picture below. I plan to cut the current p-trap arm, leaving enough of it sticking out of the cabinet to attach a coupling and connect to a new adjustable p-trap with slip joints.

what parts do I need? the piping is 1-1/4" ABS.

I presume a 1-1/4" to 1-1/4" coupling, a piece of 1-1/4" pipe, a 1-1/4 pivoting p-trap with slip joints. Will sink drain extension be needed, or goes directly into p-trap?

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that the pipe is 1-1/2". I'm not sure anything smaller is legal.

Comment: A drain kit includes the tailpiece. Whether you need an extension is anyone's guess. Are you doing this on Mars where you won't have access to a hardware store? If so, go ahead and buy extra stuff. It's pretty cheap.

Comment: its 1-1/4" ABS in bathroom sinks, in canada where I am.  Doing it on planet earth, but never done plumbing and want to make sure I get the right parts.

Comment: @isherwood is correct.  Buying extra stuff is cheaper than the gas to drive back to the store.  On the other hand, you WILL be making more than one trip.